# Problem Hibernate 5.2.18 with SQLNative and CustomeType

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, native-sql

I use Spring-orm 4.3.30 .
At Hibernate 5.1.17, class createSqlQuery use AbstractQueryImpl and we can use Custom Type with prepareStatement

for example :

```
prepareStatement.setParameter(2, reportingYear.getEndMonth(), YearMonthType.class)
```

AbstractQueryImpl :

```
public Query setParameter(int position, Object val, Type type) {
        if ( parameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterCount() == 0 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "No positional parameters in query: " + getQueryString() );
        }
        if ( position < 0 || position > parameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterCount() - 1 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Positional parameter does not exist: " + position + " in query: " + getQueryString() );
        }
        int size = values.size();
        if ( position < size ) {
            values.set( position, val );
            types.set( position, type );
        }
        else {
            // prepend value and type list with null for any positions before the wanted position.
            for ( int i = 0; i < position - size; i++ ) {
                values.add( UNSET_PARAMETER );
                types.add( UNSET_TYPE );
            }
            values.add( val );
            **types.add( type );**
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Since Hibernate 5.2 it use : NativeQueryImpl

and when we use prepareStatement with custom type.

NativeQueryImpl try to resolve type custom with SessionFactoryImpl.resolveParameterBindType

```
@Override
    public Type resolveParameterBindType(Class clazz){
        String typename = clazz.getName();      
Type type = getTypeResolver().heuristicType( typename ); 

        boolean serializable = type != null && type instanceof SerializableType;
        if ( type == null || serializable ) {
            try {
                getMetamodel().entityPersister( clazz.getName() );
            }
            catch (MappingException me) {
                if ( serializable ) {
                    return type;
                }
                else {
                    throw new HibernateException( "Could not determine a type for class: " + typename );
                }
            }
            return getTypeHelper().entity( clazz );
        }
        else {
            return type;
        }
    }
```

when call :

```
Type type = getTypeResolver().heuristicType( typename );
```

there was no custom type in TypeResolver.

```
/**
     * Retrieve the {@link Type} resolver associated with this factory.
     *
     * @return The type resolver
     *
     * @deprecated (since 5.3) No replacement, access to and handling of Types will be much different in 6.0
     */
    @Deprecated
    public TypeResolver getTypeResolver() {
        return metamodel.getTypeConfiguration().getTypeResolver();
    }
```

Knowing that @TypDef not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.tennaxia.t3.reporting.bo">
    <typedef name="YearMonth" class="com.tennaxia.t3.common.date.YearMonthType" />
```

Knowing that With JPQL, the custom type works with setParameter.

How register my type custom and can be used with Sql native query ?

Another solution is to add custom type in QueryParameterBindingsImpl.parameterMetadata but i search again how add this custom type in this parameterMetadata.

thanks a lot to help me to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parameter with the `org.hibernate.engine.spi.TypedValue` wrapper which also includes a type.